# Empty an object's properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

What are better ways of doing this code?

In the begining of my game I declare an variable for all new game information.

```
var newGameInfo = {
   players: [],
   playersList: [],
   enemies: [],
   enemiesList: [],
   drops: [],
   dropsList: [],
   attacks: [],
   attacksList: [],
   LVL: null
}
```

I later empty this variable on all it values by this code.

```
    if(newGameInfo.players.length > 0) newGameInfo.players.splice(0, newGameInfo.players.length);
    if(newGameInfo.playersList.length > 0) newGameInfo.playersList.splice(0, newGameInfo.playersList.length);
    if(newGameInfo.enemies.length > 0) newGameInfo.enemies.splice(0, newGameInfo.enemies.length);
    if(newGameInfo.enemiesList.length > 0) newGameInfo.enemiesList.splice(0, newGameInfo.enemiesList.length);
    if(newGameInfo.drops.length > 0) newGameInfo.drops.splice(0, newGameInfo.drops.length);
    if(newGameInfo.dropsList.length > 0) newGameInfo.dropsList.splice(0, newGameInfo.dropsList.length);
    if(newGameInfo.attacks.length > 0) newGameInfo.attacks.splice(0, newGameInfo.attacks.length);
    if(newGameInfo.attacksList.length > 0) newGameInfo.attacksList.splice(0, newGameInfo.attacksList.length);
    if(newGameInfo.LVL !== null) newGameInfo.LVL = null;
```

Any advice would be apriciated! :) This code takes way to much space for such a easy task.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splicing the array to empty it, just reduce its length to 0 with the same effect:

```
newGameInfo.players.length = 0;
```

To clean up the whole state at once, use something like this:

```
Object.keys(newGameInfo).forEach(function(propName) {
  // iterating over properties of `newGameInfo`
  if (Array.isArray(newGameInfo[propName])) {
    // if it's an array, empty it (but do not throw out the object!)
    newGameInfo[propName].length = 0;
  }
  else {
    newGameInfo[propName] = null;
  }
});
```

Comment: Workable, uses some neat newer JS things, still over complicated.

Comment: Please explain a little more. I don't understand 100%. It looks efficient!

Comment: Added some explanation, but frankly speaking, the code looks quite self-explanatory to me: `for each key of newGameInfo, check the type of the corresponding value, either emptying it or setting it to null (depending on type).`

Answer (score 2):

1. Put it in a function
2. Who cares what the state is if you're overwriting--get rid of the `if`s
3. If you're overwriting, why splice? Just overwrite.

Code

```
var initGameInfo = function () {
        return {
            players: [],
            playersList: [],
            enemies: [],
            enemiesList: [],
            drops: [],
            dropsList: [],
            attacks: [],
            attacksList: [],
            LVL: null
        }
    },
    newGameInfo = initGameInfo();

// game code


//reset it
newGameInfo = initGameInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to put the initialization in a function and assign the returned value on game start and reset.

```
function init() {
  return {
    players: [],
    playersList: [],
    enemies: [],
    enemiesList: [],
    drops: [],
    dropsList: [],
    attacks: [],
    attacksList: [],
    LVL: null
  }
}

var newGameInfo = init();
console.log('Logging game info');
console.log(newGameInfo);

console.log('playing the game...');
newGameInfo.LVL = 1;
newGameInfo.players.push('player 1');
newGameInfo.enemies.push('easy enemy');

console.log('Logging game info again');
console.log(newGameInfo);

console.log('Resetting');
newGameInfo = init();

console.log('Logging game info');
console.log(newGameInfo);
```

Comment: I'm not getting your comment. If it wasn't clear from the code example, you define a function that simply returns an object with empty arrays. You then execute that function and assign the returned object to a variable newGameInfo, which you use for the remainder of the game. If you want to reset the game, you simply re-execute the init function and re-assign the value to the same variable as before.

Comment: I'm with @manonthemat - I don't understand the comment, "_I'm not even..._".